# Path Include in Make/options file

Tags: c++, linux, include, file-permissions, filepath

I have a really simple problem, I think, but can't find the solution. I've included the "mathcalls.h" file into one of my projects since I need to use the `pow(double, double)` method of it. Therefore I've added the filepath to...

... the Make/options file:

```
-Iusr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits
```

... the include file of the IDE (Qt Creator):

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits
```

For the include I tried

```
#include "mathcalls.h"
#include <mathcalls.h>
```

but when building my project I get the error:

```
/home/USER/SolverNEW/multiphaseEulerFoamNEW.C:46: error: mathcalls.h:
No such file or directory
```

When looking at this, it seems the compiler is only searching in my project directory although I have added the path to file?
Please note also that in "usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits" only root has full access, others are just authorised to "access files".

How can I solve this problem professionally?

Answer (score 1):

The professional way to gain access to `double pow(double x, double y)` is:

```
#include <cmath>
```

or, at a pinch:

```
#include <math.h>
```

Then there are no issues with grovelling around sub-directories under `/usr/include`.

Comment: Both includes work, but still the method `pow(double, double)` is not found with these includes and I get the error: `SQMOM/SourceTermIntegralFunctions/IntegralFunctionBeta.H:16: error: call of overloaded ‘pow(double&, const double&)’ is ambiguous. candidates are:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:155:1: note: double pow(double, double) ...` . I also included in Make/options: `-Iusr/include` where math.h can be found.

Comment: Puzzling.  One of `pow()` or `std::pow()` should resolve, unless you're working on a defective system.  Anything down in `i386-linux-gnu/bits` under `/usr/include` is not intended to be used directly.

Comment: Try this code: `#include <cmath> #include <iostream> int main()
{ double d = std::pow(3.14, 2.78); std::cout << d << "\n"; return 0; }`.  It compiled cleanly for me both with `std::pow` and with just `pow`; the latter surprised me. I was compiling on an Ubuntu 13.10 VM with `g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror math.cc -o math`.  Please try the standalone code without any `-I` options.  If it works, try adding your `-I` options until something breaks.  Then remove that `-I` option.  I'm wondering if one of your `-I` additions picks up a file to match `<math.h>` or `<cmath>` prematurely.

Comment: I tried your code and when building I got: `19:48:27: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.` . When running the code a terminal pops up but without any output...(?). The include seems to work though.

Comment: OK; I don't build in IDEs, so I've no idea what's required.  One reason I don't use IDEs is that they don't seem to run programs of the types I write very well.  What I think I've demonstrated is that if you use the official header name and don't monkey around with the include path too much, you get the result you desire.  You may have to investigate how much complication/damage you've done to your system if you've had to do any similar operations before.

Comment: Thx, but I haven t changed much in my system, except for installing some new programs -> I'll just wait some time, perhaps someone knows whats wrong with my system.